# Android - How to animate random numbers?

Tags: android, random, numbers

I want to make a random number from 0-9 with animation.
I try to use with `ValueAnimator`, but no luck.

Here is my code without `ValueAnimator` (works):

```
final int min = 0;
final int max = 9;
final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
randomSting = String.valueOf(random);
mNumberView.setText(randomSting);
```

Here is with `ValueAnimator` that doesn't work (not works):

```
animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 9);
    final int min = 0;
    final int max = 9;
    final int random = new Random().nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    randomSting = String.valueOf(random);
    cTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            animator.setDuration(3000); 
            animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    mNumberView.setText(animation.getAnimatedValue().toString());
                }
            });
            animator.start();
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            animator.cancel();
            mNumberView.setText(randomSting);
        }
    };
    cTimer.start();
```

`mNumberView` cannot set text to `randomString`.

If possible to make number animator with random numbers, not using `ValueAnimator`

Answer (score 2):

this code will generate random number between 9 and 0 every 1 second.

```
final int min = 0;
final int max = 9;
final int duration= 1000;

final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int random = new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                handler.postDelayed(this,duration);
            }
        };
        handler.post(runnable);
```

Comment: Yes, but it will regenerate automatically after 10 sec right?

Comment: it will regenerate random number every one second.

Comment: I need just generate once with animated. Thanks

Comment: I think i did not understand completely, So you want to generate random number for example 2 and after that ValuAnimator animate from 2 to 9 ?

Comment: I want to generate random numbers from 1 until 9. But they can animate randomly maybe for 3 sec. It's like a dice but just with numbers.